# After iframe, no div value showing in webpage

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iframe, razor, internet-explorer-8, reporting-services

My application is web based and developed by MVC3 razor. I wanna show SSRS report in my page. For that I have used `iframe` tag to show SSRS report and its working fine. After the `iframe` tag I have put a `div` and included content in that.

```
    <div>
<iframe height="100"  scrolling="auto" frameborder="0"  width="100%" src="http://" />
    </div>
    <div>© 2012</div>
```

Problem: I facing problem in `div` i.e. I'm unable to view values inside the `div`.

I'm using IE8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An iframe is not a self-closing tag. You should change from `<iframe />` to `<iframe></iframe>`:

```
 <div>
  <iframe height="100"  scrolling="auto" frameborder="0"  width="100%" src="http://"></iframe>
 </div>
 <div>© 2012</div>
```

[iframe's can be self-closed with HTML5](http://www.icebluemonkey.com/blog/html/how-the-iframe-has-changed-in-html5/), but IE8 doesn't support this.

Comment: i wonder how years old answers are still helping! every problem i face have been faced by others years ago! still a long way to go! thanks for this answer :P

Answer (score 1):

Your iframe code is missing the closing, you should change your code to 
    <div>
<iframe height="100"  scrolling="auto" frameborder="0"  width="100%" src="http://" ></iframe>
</div>
<div>© 2012</div><div>
<iframe height="100"  scrolling="auto" frameborder="0"  width="100%" src="http://" ></iframe>
</div>
<div>© 2012</div>